# How to print on the Next Page in c#

Tags: c#, printing, barcode

I want to print on to the NextPageusing printdocument in C#. The code I am using keeps on incrementing the number of pages to the infinite loop.

[image]

The code I am using is as follows:

```
PaperSize pze = new PaperSize("Custom Paper size", 800, 150);

public void Print()
{
     printDocument1.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = pze;
     printDocument1.Print();
}
int YHeight = 0;
private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender,     System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
        panel1_Paint(sender, new PaintEventArgs(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle));
        int heightOfPage = 150;
        float pageHeight = e.MarginBounds.Height;
        while (heightOfPage + 100 < pageHeight && YHeight < this.SaveBeforePrint.Count)
        {

            YHeight += 1;
            heightOfPage += 20;
        }

        if (YHeight < this.SaveBeforePrint.Count)
        {
            e.HasMorePages = true;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, the title of question says next line and first line of your post says print on next page. What actually you want to achieve and whats happening right now ?

Comment: You should consider using more distinctive names between `pageHeight` and `heightOfPage`. The problem probably is that `YHeight` at some point is not increased anymore, but is still lower than `this.SaveBeforePrint.Count`.

Comment: Sorry I want to print on the Next Page.. Edited my quetion @JibranKhan

Comment: what is the source of data ? i mean from where are you reading these images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi change your PrintPage method as below ..

here countInRow is the count of barcode in a row on each page to display ..

```
int countInRow = 3;  // number of barcode in a row on every page.

private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{        
   panel1_Paint(sender, new PaintEventArgs(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle));

   int locCount = SaveBeforePrint.Count;
   for (int i = 0; i < countInRow && i < locCount; i++)
   {
      SaveBeforePrint.RemoveAt(0);        //remove the top element always
   }
   e.HasMorePages = (SaveBeforePrint.Count > 0);
}
```

you have to make one more change in **"panel1_Paint"** method also, change the for loop condition

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
  .
  .
  .
    for (int serial = 0; serial < SaveBeforePrint.Count && serial < countInRow; serial++)
    {
     // you code goes here.. 
    }
  .
  .
  .
}
```